# How to Unwrap Wrapped PL/SQL Packages?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

For Oracle 12C+ versions, we are wrapping code now . How do we make sure that the correct version of PL/SQL Packages have been deployed. Before we had dba source to check , but after the wrapping of code , it is almost not possible. Is there any good way to know the amendment of the packages/functions  ?

Any suggestions on how do people confirm if the correct module has been deployed ?

Comment: You could have a version number embedded - perhaps automatically by your toolchain- in the package spec (as a constant) or body (exposed via a function)? But why can't you use dba_source now - you can still compare the text can't you; or a checksum of the text if that's easier for you?

Comment: Maybe wrap only the package body.

Comment: Yes, typically package headers should not be wrapped. That said, there are a number of web sites out there that will allow you to copy/paste wrapped code and unwrap it for you; just run a Google search. Code wrapping is only obfuscation, not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I would create own static function with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-E918087C-D5A8-4CEE-841B-5333DE6D4C15)

like

```
...
function version
   return varchar2
as 
   constant ver varchar2:= '{@ver}';
begin 
   return $$PLSQL_UNIT||':'||ver;
end;
...
```